# modify regex to replace only letters outside of curly braces and exclude punctuation

Tags: regex

I have a regex that replaces all characters with the letter "z" that live outside curly braces. however I only want to replace characters a-z and A-Z.  How can I modify the regex to do so?

in javascript:

```
let str = "hours, plural, =1 {hour} other {hours}";
str.replace(/[^{}](?=([^{}]*\{[^{}]*\})*[^{}]*$)/g, 'z');
```

this results in:

```
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{hour}zzzzzzz{hours}
```

but should be:

```
zzzzz, zzzzzz, =1 {hour} zzzzz {hours}
```

thanks!

Comment: Is it JavaScript? C#? Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex for search:

```
/[a-zA-Z](?![^{]*})/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b99niY/1)

**Description:**

- `[a-zA-Z]`: Match a letter `a-z` or `A-Z`
- `(?![^{]*})`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a closing `}` ahead of us without opening `{` in between.

**Code:**

```js
const regex = /[a-zA-Z](?![^{]*})/g;
const str = `hours, plural, =1 {hour} other {hours}`;

const result = str.replace(regex, 'z');

console.log(result);
//=> zzzzz, zzzzzz, =1 {hour} zzzzz {hours}
```